# call 2 functions in html

Tags: javascript, html

In my game1.html i have a function called Showhide()

i call this via:

```
<<button id="button" onclick="showhide()">Click Me</button>
```

but in my init.js i have a function this is how the function is called:

```
 document.getElementById('bodyresize').onclick = function()
```

but now i need those 2 in 1 html button so when i press a button showhide first does something and then the function in init.js does something

Do you guys know how to do that?

Comment: try `document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() { showhide(); other_function();};`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
<button id="button" onclick="showhide(); otherFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

Of course to make it work, you need to modify the anonymous function attached to bodyresize button to a named function. That means you'll need to change this in init.js:

```
document.getElementById('bodyresize').onclick = function() {
// some stuff here
}
```

into this:

```
document.getElementById('bodyresize').onclick = anotherFunction;

function anotherFunction() {
// some stuff here
}
```

Comment: hi

That doesnt work then i get onclick of null error
the button with bodyresize is also an id so that is like this
<button id="button" onclick="showhide(); otherFunction()">Click Me</button>

But in one button your code doesnt work

Comment: @sgouman - I'm not sure if I get your comment correctly, but the problem is with the other button with id bodyresize ? Do you want this button to call both functions or just the one from your init.js ? Also note, that if you want this anonymous function being called from two places, you should name it.

Comment: hi
Right now i have 2 slperate buttons:
this one wich calls showhide()
<button id="button" onclick="showhide()">Click Me</button> 

and this one wich calls bodyresize in the init.js

<button id="bodyresize">Click Me test</button>

but i cant get that in one button that is what i need

Comment: @sgouman - I've extedned my anwser. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use javascript code in html. This is a bad practice. And show your html, possible here works nesting of elements and javascript Events bubbling. You need use that:

```
var bodyresize = document.getElementById('bodyresize');
bodyresize.addEventListener('click', function () {
   // function body
}, false);
```

In html dont use javascript:

```
<button id="button">Click Me</button> 

var btn = document.getElementById('button');
btn.addEventListenr('click', function () {

}, false);
```

Comment: sorry i dont really understand it
thsi code <button id="button" onclick="showhide(); otherFunction()">Click Me</button> 

doesnt work because i guess that its not really a function beacuse of this line:

document.getElementById('bodyresize').onclick = function()